# Access widget properties inside of add_widget method

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to make a custom set of widgets and in some of them I would like to access specific widgets' properties **inside of the `add_widget(widget, index, canvas)`method**.

The problem is that the properties are always empty. This could be because I access them early but how do I fix it?

My Code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class CustomWidget(BoxLayout):

    def add_widget(self, widget, index=0, canvas=None):
        if isinstance(widget, MDLabel):
            # Why is the text empty?
            # Also how can I get the text value?
            print("{}'s text is: {}".format(widget, widget.text))
        else:
            super(CustomWidget, self).add_widget(widget, index, canvas)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
CustomWidget:
    MDLabel:
        text: "Some text"
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is empty because it hasn't been set yet at the time it's added to the parent.

If you care about what its value changes to, you can bind to the new child widget's `text` property in `add_widget` so that you are notified when it changes and can act accordingly.